# Redux: getState in action

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I change the general state through other actions and when I need to fetch posts I'm doing this:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let state = getState().postReducer
  let options = {
    order: state.order,
    page: state.page,
    per: state.per,
    search: state.search
  }
  let params = generateParams(options)

  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/posts?${params}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => dispatch(receivePosts(response)))
}
```

Is it ok or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using getState to get the state and use as you did is ok. Nothing is wrong about it. Even I find it easier to maintain rather than getting the redux state and passing to action creators from components.